# send a document using a specific template docusign java

Tags: docusignapi

see my scenario. I already have my environment configuring using the docusign sdk java using the intellj idea. the examples are all working.

I created a template on the development portal. What do I need to do and send a document using a specific template. In the portal I will have a template where the person who will receive it will need to sign. How do I do via sdk java?

Answer (score 0):

**Update:** this is the [code in the Java SDK](https://github.com/docusign/docusign-java-client/blob/a91f2a7521b484d1b4febf7c0a2b476b02e5e0ff/src/main/java/com/docusign/esign/api/EnvelopesApi.java#L7817) to udpate a document:

```
public void updateDocument(String accountId, String envelopeId, String documentId)
```

[This article](https://developers.docusign.com/docs/esign-rest-api/how-to/request-signature-template-remote/) has code examples in all languages including Java using the SDK.

I also suggest to try to use [Quickstart](https://developers.docusign.com/docs/esign-rest-api/quickstart/) so the authentication part of making API calls is handled for you.

Here is part of the Java code you will need:

```
private EnvelopeDefinition makeEnvelope(WorkArguments args) {
    String signerEmail = args.getSignerEmail();
    String signerName = args.getSignerName();
    String ccEmail = args.getCcEmail();
    String ccName = args.getCcName();
    String templateId = args.getTemplateId();


    EnvelopeDefinition env = new EnvelopeDefinition();
    env.setTemplateId(templateId);

    TemplateRole signer1 = new TemplateRole();
    signer1.setEmail(signerEmail);
    signer1.setName(signerName);
    signer1.setRoleName("signer");

    TemplateRole cc1 = new TemplateRole();
    cc1.setEmail(ccEmail);
    cc1.setName(ccName);
    cc1.setRoleName("cc");

    env.setTemplateRoles(Arrays.asList(signer1, cc1));
    env.setStatus("sent");
    return env;
}
```

Comment: I'm sorry for the question. but I’ve already studied all the quickstart examples.

1) I already created the model on the portal with subscription.

2) I will generate a local pdf file and I need to send it to the api for certain recipients, using a specific template.

in the quickstart sample models do you have one that does this?

Comment: We don't have a specific example showing this scenario, but you can do it using either composite templates, or by removing the env.setStatus("sent"); above, and then updating the document before it is sent out using an updatedocument() method.

Comment: but can I do this scenario above by sdk?

Comment: yes you can, as long as the envelope is in "draft" state (not yet sent out) you can update the document with any other document using the Java SDK

Comment: have any example?

Comment: how to define in my envelope that the recipient will have to sign either via electronic signature or via digital certificate?

Comment: Well, if you want digital certificate, you first need to get it for your account. Can you do this without writing code? from the web app do you see this option? if not - you'll have to get this enabled on your account first.